# Obtener un valor único LEFT JOIN

Tags: sqlite, join

Hola tengo tres tablas con los siguientes registros: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que me devuelva valores sólo si una fecha en la Tabla_3 no se encuentra en la Tabla_2, pero existe en la Tabla_1. Realicé un query pero no me da el resultado que requiero ya que me arroja el valor que encuentra en las tres tablas:

```
SELECT ik.* FROM
  (SELECT Tabla_3.Fecha,Tabla_3.Folio 
  FROM
  (Tabla_3
  LEFT JOIN Tabla_2 ON Tabla_3.Fecha=Tabla_2.Fecha))ik
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT Tabla_1.Fecha,Tabla_1.Folio 
  FROM
  (Tabla_2
  LEFT JOIN Tabla_1 ON Tabla_1.Fecha=Tabla_2.Fecha))jk
ON ik.Fecha=jk.Fecha
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu mejor opción es utilizar el operador "in", por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla_3
WHERE Fecha not IN (select Fecha from Tabla_2)
and   Fecha IN (select Fecha from Tabla_1)
```

Espero te ayude.